# Implementation of Generalized Advantage Function

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I was a lot of implementations of GAEs (https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02438) using loops, but I though it could be interpreted as a convolution with an exponential decay filter:

[image]

Considering the following as estimation:

[image]

So I've implemented it as follows:

```
class GAEAlgorithm(Algorithm):
    def __init__(self, discount, lambda_coefficient=0.9):
        self.discount = discount
        self.lambda_coefficient = lambda_coefficient

    def gae(self, advantages):
        # advantages.shape == (batch size, time, 1)
        t = tf.range(advantages.shape[1], dtype=tf.float32)
        kernel = (self.discount * self.lambda_coefficient)**t
        kernel = kernel[:, None, None]
        advantages = tf.pad(advantages, [[0,0], [0, advantages.shape[1]-1], [0,0]])
        res = tf.nn.conv1d(advantages, kernel, 1, padding="VALID")
        return res
```

I've tested it as follows:

```
class GAEAlgorithm(Algorithm):
   ...
   def test(self):
        self.discount = 1
        print(self.gae(tf.convert_to_tensor([
            [3,2,1],
            [5,6,7],
        ], dtype=tf.float32)[..., None]))
GAEAlgorithm(1,1).test()
```

And it seems to the working, but maybe another pair of eyes might spot corner cases where this is not valid